# Dual-coding for SQL Server and SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, sqlite

I want to code an application for both SQL Server and SQLite, but not have to duplicate all database access (that would clearly be unworkable!).

Is there any way of creating a class where the DB access is handled as required, but presented to the rest of the application as set of more generic common objects (i.e. a `DataSet`, a `DataTable`, etc.) irrespective of which DB the data was retrieved from?

Comment: 1) That's what ADO.NET does already. Just use the abstract classes like DbConnection, DbCommand. 2) Use a micro-ORM like Dapper or a full ORM like Entity Framework, NHibernate

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have some pretty good starting points in the .NET framework. Almost all database actions are abstracted away in interfaces, like [`IDbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `IDbCommand`, `IDataReader`, etc. It is pretty easy to do if you rely on the interfaces (I have done it for our company supporting a lot of database platforms).

There are two common problems you have to tackle:

- Specifying and creating of the connection (in our case find and load some drivers too). The [`DbProviderFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be of help;
- Different database implementations of SQL. Consensus: rely on the shared subset only, or create an intermediary layer that abstracts this away.

We have written our own, but there are also frameworks that do this all for you already, like Entity Framework.

Comment: @Jim: need more help?